# Music genres are wrong in iTunes Match on iOS

Tags: itunes-match

I am running the latest version of iTunes and use iTunes Match, all my music is properly tagged (mostly from iTunes built in lookup).

However, on my iOS devices (iPhone and iPad) the Genres are all wrong.  I can't figure out where iTunes Match has got the Genre info from as it is way off.

Comment: Can you give some examples?

Comment: The Christmas genre on my iPhone (it is that time of year!) has lots of albums in it that are not in the Christmas genre on my iTunes. An example would be Balaeric House Map II - this is dance music and is in the House genre on my iTunes.

Comment: On further investigation it seems that certain albums are appearing in multiple genres. The Balaeric House Map II compilation above is one example.  Another would be Top 100 Dance hits, which I have added to the "Pop" genre but on my iPhone appears in these genres: Breakdance, Children's, Chillout and Christmas but not in Asian, Blues or Audiobook.

Comment: More investigations show that any album with the Album Artist as Various Artists are all grouped together irrespective of genre. So when I go into the Christmas genre, I see Various Artists, when I go into that it shows me ALL albums that have Various Artists and the genre is disregarded.